# TestDriven.Net 3.0 does not have TestDriven.NET.Solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testdriven.net

I am trying out TestDriven.Net 3.0 (RTM) under VS2010 ultimate (x86) but could not find TestDriven.NET.Solution in bindings under keyboard options in VS.

Is it recently removed or is my build bugged?

I do not want to right click the whole solution then run tests...

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find it's been removed.  I'd suggest you contact them via the [support page](http://testdriven.net/support.aspx) if you want it back.